# Crashed LMs visible on LRO images?

Tags: apollo-program, lro

I'm rewatching the old HBO "From the Earth to the Moon" series and then reading up about specific missions in detail afterwards. One thing I hadn't realised was that the LM for each mission typically crashed onto the moon after it emptied and separated from the CSM.  For Apollo 12 the wikipedia article notes the location where Intrepid crashed.

Give that we have great photos from LRO you'd think we could hunt down the crashed LMs.  I tried looking at the archive but didn't find a way to get a specific image relating to specific co-ordinates.  Anyone know how I could do this?

Comment: A list of all LEMs including crash coordinates can be found here: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2496/where-were-the-various-apollo-lunar-modules-lms-discarded

Comment: and the LROC has a bunch of impact sites, but not the LEM ascent modules: http://www.lroc.asu.edu/featured_sites/

Comment: Coordinates are the same as I've seen elsewhere, much appreciated, it's just trying to find high res images of these coordinates to try to spot the LMs :)

Comment: They found the Chinese lander with the LRO--it's two pixels across.  The crashed LEMs are going to be awfully hard to see.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

See this [paper](https://www.hou.usra.edu/meetings/lpsc2017/pdf/1031.pdf) from P. J. Stooke, Department of Geography and Centre for Planetary Science and Exploration, University of Western Ontario, London, Ontario, Canada about the Apollo 12 and 14 impact sides.

Many details and images about impact sites in this [page](http://apollo.mem-tek.com/A12_LM_impact_site/A12_LM_impact_site.html) with additional data about Apollo 15 and 17.

A NASA [page](https://history.nasa.gov/SP-4029/Apollo_18-29_LM_Lunar_Impact.htm) with the Lunar coordinates of the impact sites of Apollo 12, 14, 15 and 17. Another NASA [page](https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/lunar/apollo_impact.html) about Impact Sites of Apollo LM Ascent and SIVB Stages.

Good luck for finding more crash site images.

There are small differences of the coordinates from Stoke: 3.920° S, 21.172° W and NASA: -3.94 (deg N) -21.20 (deg E) for Apollo 12. For Apollo 14 only the longitudes are different: 19.637° W and -19.67 (deg E).

Comment: Thanks - as a result I found this http://wms.lroc.asu.edu/lroc/search